# tabbar controller's tabbar is not getting hid 

Tags: iphone

I am using a UITabBarController in my application and when I switch between tabs I want to hide the tabbar in one of the tabs.

I tried

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

Although the tabs dont appear I can still see the tabbar on the bottom of my screen.

I also tried setting the frame of tabbar but of no use. I tried setting height of it to zero which was also of no use.

my app design is something similar to this. I have two navigation controllers with root view controllers initialised and I added these navigation controllers to a tabbar controller. I've searched other related topics and tried methods told over there but nothing helped me.

Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not directly hide the tab bar like this. Tab bar can be hidden/unhidden while pushing/popping views like:

```
SampleViewController *obj = [[SampleViewController alloc] init];
[obj setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
[obj release];
```